# MATLAB - How to get a variable to sweep between two set points

Tags: matlab

I basically want an angle (GA_theta) to start at 225 deg and sweep until 290 deg, where it then reverses until 225 deg and then reverses again and so on. I'm not familiar with MATLAB and can't figure this out.

```
clc; clear all;

%Length of Links
GA = 4;

GA_tmax = 290;
GA_tmin = 225;

t = 0:0.05:10;

ang_speed = 20;
GA_theta = GA_tmin + (ang_speed*t);

G = [0;0];
A = GA*[cosd(GA_theta);sind(GA_theta)];

for i=1:length(t);

   ani = subplot(1,1,1);

   GA = line([G(1) A(1,i)],[G(2) A(2,i)]);

   axis(ani,'equal');
   set(gca,'XLim',[-5 5],'YLim',[-5 5]);

   str2 = ['Time elapsed: '  num2str(t(i)) ' s'];
   Time = text(-2,4,str2);
   pause(0.005);

   if i<length(t)
    delete(GA);
    delete(Time);
    grid on;
   end

end
```

Comment: Trying to learn it, has toolboxes that will make future project easier

Comment: That's great. But you should first try to learn it, then ask questions about it. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service, asking here can't be a substitute for learning a language yourself. Start with the "Getting started" bit of MATLAB's documentation, you can learn the basics of the language starting from there.

Comment: I always do try to learn first, I know the basics, but I'm just stuck on this one problem. I've already attempted it a few ways but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Your current code has almost nothing to do with your question. Reduce your problem to a [mcve], and when you do that, you'll probably see the specific step where you're stuck. It's not clear what you want to do, but it's probably just some simple *array concatenation*.

Comment: You may want to read this [basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf) document. Note that you probably want to write a function doing this. Either that or hardcode the angular velocity with a direction. Note that you have set the angular speed to constant, but it is not. The absolute velocity is, but the direction is not. The guess is that this should be a function of the time.